# Why ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click().perform() twice

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to crawl the wechat public accounts includes the key word through http://weixin.sogou.com

But i find i must use **twice** `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nextpage).click().perform()`，it can still work,and go to the next page !

who can tell me why and how to fix ! Thank you!

The source code are as follow , and sorry the comments are in the Chinese .

```
# coding=utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

key = u"江南大学"  #搜索的关键词
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://weixin.sogou.com/")
assert u'搜狗微信' in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("upquery")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(key)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("swz2") #搜索公众号
button.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.title_contains(key)
)
count = 0
while True:
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            wechat_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sogou_vr_11002301_box_{}\"]/div[2]/h3".format(i)).text
            print wechat_name
            wechat_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sogou_vr_11002301_box_{}\"]/div[2]/h4/span/label".format(i)).text
            print wechat_id
            wechat_intro = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sogou_vr_11002301_box_{}\"]/div[2]/p[1]/span[2]".format(i)).text
            print wechat_intro
            print "*************************"
            count += 1
        except:
            pass
    try:
        nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sogou_next\"]") #下一页的按钮
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(nextpage)
        actions.click().
        actions.perform()
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(nextpage)
        actions.click().
        actions.perform()
    except Exception,e:
        print e
        break
driver.quit()
print count
```

Comment: I find an answer: `action.move_to_element(nextpage).perform`first and then `action.click().perform()`. it can works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain your action, so no need to do perform after each action.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(nextpage)
actions.click(nextpage)
actions.perform()
```

**OR**

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(nextpage)
actions.click(nextpage).perform()
```

Comment: You can try and you will find it must use twice

Comment: I posted the answer after testing it, moreover you check the documentation here
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html